# data-class equivalent of `_1`-style tuple lens shortcut?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

As per its [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:_1), Haskell's `lens` library's `_1` provides a lens for tuples.

For data records, there are instead several other functions such as `makeLenses`, automatically generating lenses based on the record's field names.

Unfortunately, I am dealing with data classes without named fields, meaning `makeLenses` appears out for me.
This makes me wonder. `_1` seems quite convenient, yet as implied in its documentation, appears not to work on data classes. Is there an equivalent of a similar level of convenience?

```hs
> :set -package lens
> import Control.Lens
> (1,2) ^. _1
1
> data Bar = Bar String deriving Show
> bar = Bar "abc"
> bar ^. _1

<interactive>:271:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Field1 Bar Bar b b
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall b. Field1 Bar Bar b b => b
```

Adding the `FlexibleContexts` extension, I instead face another error:

```hs
bar ^. _1

<interactive>:6:1: error:
    • No instance for (Field1 Bar Bar () ()) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: `makeLenses` could instantiate the `Fieldn` classes. Strange that it doesn't. Maybe open a bug report and/or a pull request. https://github.com/ekmett/lens

Comment: If you want to access fields by position, there's also [generic-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens).

Comment: @luqui thanks, that sounds pretty cool! I hadn't actually tried `makeLenses` here yet, but couldn't quite figure it out. That's probably on me, as I find the template haskell generated statements a bit opaque to debug, but the other library seems to have done it for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Field1` has a default generic implementation, so you can probably add an instance yourself:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Bar = Bar String deriving (Show, Generic)

instance Field1 Bar Bar String String
```

generic-lens also provides the same functionality, without requiring that boilerplate instance. `_1` is called `position @1` (from [`Data.Generics.Product`(`.Positions`)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-1.2.0.1/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Positions.html)).

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me -- `generic-lens` looks pretty good! :)

Comment: whelp, guess in my real use-case involving multiple non-overlapping constructors this no longer works. oh well!